# How to get current user's attributes such as phone number or email in Cognito AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to Cognito AWS and am using it for a mobile application. I wanted to know how to get the current user's attributes like username, phone number or email id using the userid?

Below is the code in which i want to get the user attributes (made using the AWS tutorial).

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

@Override
public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
    PinpointConfiguration pinpointConfig = new PinpointConfiguration(
            getApplicationContext(),
            AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider(),
            AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration());
    pinpointManager = new PinpointManager(pinpointConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    // Start a session with Pinpoint
    pinpointManager.getSessionClient().resumeSession();

    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
    this.dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder().dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient).awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration()).build();
    identityManager = new IdentityManager(getApplicationContext(), AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration());
```